# How to use different font and shape characters properly in headers?

Tags: fonts, macros, table-of-contents

I'm using Kpfonts for the text of my documents, but I'd like to use the Computer Modern italic ampersand in my headings. To this end, I've defined a command `\amp` to insert the proper character. The first attempt is

```
\newcommand\amp{{\fontfamily{cmr}\fontshape{it}\selectfont\&}}
```

But that doesn't work because there's no bold italic CM, so I have to use the bx series instead:

```
\newcommand\amp{{\usefont{T1}{cmr}{bx}{it}\&}}
```

Which works. But now I have bold ampersands in the page headers (this is a thesis, so I've got chapter and section titles on top of non-title pages). After some fiddling, I get this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\amp{{\if\f@series b\usefont{T1}{cmr}{bx}{it}\else\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{it}\fi\&}}
\makeatother
```

This gives me the right weight in the right place in titles and page heads, but now the table of contents gets the wrong font, because `\amp` is expanded when the stuff is added to the .toc file, and at that time the font series is m and not b.

Is there some way I can get this to do the right thing in all three places? I suppose I have to somehow delay expansion of the macro in the appropriate way, but I've no idea how...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\protect\amp` does the trick.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kpfonts}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\amp{{\if\f@series b\usefont{T1}{cmr}{bx}{it}\else\usefont{T1}{cmr}{m}{it}\fi\&}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Barnes \protect\amp\ Noble}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: D'oh. When something untoward happens in titles and such `\protect` is of course the way. Thanks!